# Show custom page while the server processes a form

Tags: 6, batch-operations

Form submit handler sends some time consuming requests to other servers. I need to show custom page with some simple content like timer/progress-bar/images while server will process submitted data.

Not sure how this could be properly done in Drupal 6.26.

Found useful batch tool (set_batch()), but didn't figure out how to replace default progress-bar with custom page and content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an onclick event handler for submit button and add a DIV with a loading image with `display:none` attribute in CSS.

```
function show_loading_icon(){
  $("#loading_icon").show();
}
```

So when you click on submit button a DIV will now become visible which you can use to dispaly a loading icon. Once form is submitted it will reload page and DIV will be hidden again.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the module [loader](http://drupal.org/project/loader) , it may solve your problem

A similar module [hide_submit](http://drupal.org/project/hide_submit)